Efficient way to find the expected value of the exponent of two 6 sided die
Given you roll two fair six sided die x and y with faces from 1 to 6, is there any trick to calculate the expected value of x^y?
I believe you could calculate the expected value of each of 1^y, 2^y ... 6^y as partial sums of six different geometric series, then divide by 6, but I wonder if there is any smarter way that involves less arithmetic to arrive at the final answer.

mean(outer(1:6,1:6,"^")) in R requires little thought or typing, assuming the two dice are independent.

@Henry that is even more brute force and requires even more arithmetic.
i was wondering if there were any closed-formed shortcuts on the way to the answer.

Possibly, though $\frac{1}{6^2}\left(6+\sum\limits_{x=2}^6 \frac{x(x^6-1)}{x-1}\right)$ needs more thought, typing and checking, especially since the geometric series partial sum does not work for $x=1$.
